# How to use value from object1.property as a property for object2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In my angular component's template, **I'm trying to achieve something like this:**

```
<div> {{object1.some_property.(get value from object2.property and use it here, as it is a property of object1)}} </div>
```

Is it possible in JavaScript using some ES6 format or in typescript?
If not, should I use some variable in the template to store the object's value and fetch it from there?
If yes,then how?

Comment: Hi, have you tried {{object1.some_property[object2.property]}} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like {{object1.some_property[object2.property]}} ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> {{object1.some_property.[get.value.from.your.other.object.and.put.it.in.square.brackets.like.this.as.thats.associative.arrays.notation.which.you.can.use.for.any.object.property]}} </div>
```

Comment: I'll give this a try! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: please add some Explanation on the changes you made (and why the changes should be made) in order to hep future readers to understand the error and the solution better. thanks!

Comment: explanation is in the code itself